# org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException,tomcat can not get date

Tags: java, spring-boot, wechat

When I change `@RequestBody` to `@RequestParam`, it throws this exception.

[image: this is what hearers show]

It throws out `title' not exit`,but i have defined title in bean
[image: it throws out "'title' not exit",but i have defined title in bean]

```
@RequestMapping(value="post")
public void throwpost(@RequestParam(value="title") String title,@RequestParam(value="destination") String destination,
        @RequestParam(value="time") String time,@RequestParam(value="plan") String plan){
    System.out.println("dd");
    System.out.println(title);
    System.out.println(destination);
    //System.out.println(threshold);
    System.out.println(time);
    System.out.println(plan);
    //postservice.makepost(title,plan, destination,threshold, time);
}
```

Comment: Could you give us the stracktrace ?

Comment: why my front desk and background name are set to title,but it does not exist for title.and there is no output in the background.

Answer (score 0):

My friend there is difference between `@RequestParam` and `@RequestBody`, you seems to want to use `@RequestBody` attributes in `@RequestParam`.
You can search the differences between these `@RequestParam`,`@RequestBody` and `@PathVariable` for better understanding of the usage of all these three. Defiantly that search will help you.

Comment: Actually,what i want to ask is,why do i use ajax to pass the value to the background,bht the background is not processed.you can see the picture i uploaded.